# Select MIN value from multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a very basic database for keeping track of point scores for 6 different events. Each event has 4 events within it.

My Current SQL query is very basic, and looks very similar to what is below;

```
Select Name, 
       SUM(ISNULL(p.e1_e1_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e1_e2_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e1_e3_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e1_e4_points, 0)) AS Event1, 
       SUM(ISNULL(p.e2_e1_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e2_e2_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e2_e3_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e2_e4_points, 0)) AS Event2,
       SUM(ISNULL(p.e3_e1_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e3_e2_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e3_e3_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e3_e4_points, 0)) AS Event3,
       SUM(ISNULL(p.e4_e1_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e4_e2_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e4_e3_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e4_e4_points, 0)) AS Event4,
       SUM(ISNULL(p.e5_e1_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e5_e2_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e5_e3_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e5_e4_points, 0)) AS Event5,
       SUM(ISNULL(p.e6_e1_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e6_e2_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e6_e3_points, 0)+ISNULL(p.e6_e4_points, 0)) AS Event6
       from points
```

I need to be able to add an additional column, which is the lowest value from columns (being Event1, Event2, Event3, etc).

Answer (score 15):

Basically, this is about finding a row-wise minimum.

There is an elegant inline solution in the most upvoted answer to this Stack Overflow question:

- [SQL MAX of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns)

According to that solution, if you have a table `T` of this kind:

```
C1  C2  C3
--  --  --
…   …   …
…   …   …
```

you can find a row-wise minimum like this:

```
SELECT
  C1,
  C2,
  C3,
  (
    SELECT MIN(C)
    FROM (VALUES (C1), (C2), (C3) AS v (C)
  ) AS MinC
FROM
  T
;
```

Basically you are arranging the values of `C1`, `C2`, `C3` as a column and are applying a normal (column-wise) aggregate function to it to find the minimum.

Now in your case the `C1`, `C2` etc. are expressions. Usually that is fine, you can use the `VALUES` row constructor with expressions. But in this case each expression already contains an aggregate function (`SUM()`), which prevents us from applying the method directly (`VALUES` expressions must not use aggregate functions).

However, that issue is easily resolved. You can use your current query as a derived table or a CTE and apply the method at the outer level, where the expressions will be just references, like this:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  Event1,
  Event2,
  Event3,
  Event4,
  Event5,
  Event6,
  (
    SELECT MIN(Event)
    FROM (VALUES (Event1), (Event2), (Event3), (Event4), (Event5), (Event6)) AS v (Event)
  ) AS MinEvent
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ... /* your current query */
  ) AS derived
;
```

And here is an identical solution but using a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS
  (
    SELECT
      ... /* your current query */
  )
SELECT
  Name,
  Event1,
  Event2,
  Event3,
  Event4,
  Event5,
  Event6,
  (
    SELECT MIN(Event)
    FROM (VALUES (Event1), (Event2), (Event3), (Event4), (Event5), (Event6)) AS v (Event)
  ) AS MinEvent
FROM
  cte
;
```

---

`CROSS APPLY` is another option (with either derived table or CTE).

The [`LEAST` logical function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-least-transact-sql) is available in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only). It is not currently available in SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Note,  LEAST function is available in SQL Server 2022 now

Answer (score 3):

I've set up a dbfiddle example simulating your data:

> ```
> create table events (name varchar(20), event1 int, event2 int, event3 int, event4 int);
> insert into events values 
> ('name1',10,11,12,13),('name2',20,21,22,23),('name3',30,31,32,33);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

IMHO you have some options:

**NESTED IIF**

> ```
> -- this is your query
> with a as
> (
>     select name, event1, event2, event3, event4
>     from   events
> )
> select name, event1, event2, event3, event4,
>        iif (event1 < event2, event1, 
>               iif(event2 < event3, event2, 
>                   iif(event3 < event4, event3, event4))) min_event
> from a;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | event1 | event2 | event3 | event4 | min_event
> :---- | -----: | -----: | -----: | -----: | --------:
> name1 |     10 |     11 |     12 |     13 |        10
> name2 |     20 |     21 |     22 |     23 |        20
> name3 |     30 |     31 |     32 |     33 |        30
> ```

**UNPIVOT**

You can use an UNPIVOT solution to get the minimum value in this way:

> ```
> with a as
> (
>     select name, event1, event2, event3, event4
>     from events
> )
> , b as
> (
>     select name, min(event) as min_event
>     from   a
>     unpivot (event for n in([event1],[event2],[event3],[event4])) upv
>     group by name
> )
> select a.name, a.event1, a.event2, a.event3, a.event4, b.min_event
> from   a
> join   b
> on     b.name = a.name
>
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | event1 | event2 | event3 | event4 | min_event
> :---- | -----: | -----: | -----: | -----: | --------:
> name1 |     10 |     11 |     12 |     13 |        10
> name2 |     20 |     21 |     22 |     23 |        20
> name3 |     30 |     31 |     32 |     33 |        30
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1089a7cfa16a0969e2f04aa834c17e78)*